# Rails trying to connect postgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

** Im trying to use postgreSQL as my db but its giving me this error when i try to migrate or create database **

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 3.0/pg_ext
C:/Users/saraa/Documents/intern-ship/q-a/config/application.rb:20:in `<main>'
C:/Users/saraa/Documents/intern-ship/q-a/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- pg_ext
C:/Users/saraa/Documents/intern-ship/q-a/config/application.rb:20:in `<main>'
C:/Users/saraa/Documents/intern-ship/q-a/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

** database.yml looks like this**
development:
  <<: *default
    database: question_a
    encoding: unicode
    username: postgres
    host: localhost
    port: 5432
```

**i tried uninstalling postqreSQL and the gem files and installing the bundles but i dont have any success  **
the versions im using
postgresql 13
pg (1.2.3, 0.18.4 x64-mingw32)
rails 6.1.3.2

EDIT Also im on windows

Comment: Can you show your Gemfile, Idealluy it should have `gem 'pg' ` and then run `bundle install`

Comment: yeah i have added it i added the gem "pg" to my gem file after that i ran "bundle install" but no luck cant even start my server i found few solution but turns out i have to downgrade the rails version im using